# Insert data from one .dbf table to another .dbf table in foxpro 6

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have two foxpro tables, one is aa2.dbf and another is tradeinfo.dbf. I need to insert some data from tradeinfo.dbf table to aa2.dbf table within a daterange. Date field is bookdate, I write the following code in visual foxpro 6.

```
use aa2.dbf
zap
appen from tradeinfo for between (bookdate,ctod(thisform.txtfrom.value),ctod(thisform.txtto.value))
```

thisform.txtfrom.value and thisform.txtto.value contains from and to date.

It shows me an error

'Function argument value ,type or count is invalid in foxpro 6'.

How can I solve that?or, How can I perform the tasks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Function argument value ,type or count is invalid in foxpro 6"_ -- There has never been a "native" Vfp error message saying that in any Vfp version,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^^^^^

&& assign mdatefrom and mdateto as ControlSource of textfrom and textto ..

&& you can work with text fields and convert with CTOD() after

^^^^

mdatefrom=date()-30 && date 30 days ago, change as needed

mdateto=date() && today's date

use aa2

zap

append from tradeinfo for bookdate>=mdatefrom .and. bookdate<=mdateto

go top

brow

======

Take care,

Sime

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted it, but your reply does not provide anything that would solve the problem.

Comment: 1/2 ) You're welcome. I know it's only a workaround but it will work. And I do acknowledge it doesn't answer the function argument value issue, as stated above. 
Will this pass on a PhD thesis in Foxpro? Of course not. 
Will it provide another way of solving the problem? Apparently, it did. 
I come from an old school (and plenty of spaghetti code!) where this is acceptable, albeit not good enough for academic and theoretical settings ...

Comment: 2/2) Don't get me wrong, I've always appreciated and I'm a big fan of both Stefan and Cetin, two of the dozen real Foxpro gurus I've known of. 
Along with Mike Lewis, Chris Miller, Mike Gagnon, Griff. 
Always to the point and with great texts and examples, true teachers: Tamar Granor, Marcia Akins, alvechurchdata, Barbara Peisch. 
And, in a category by itself, my favorite by a mile: the great Olaf Doschke!

Comment: It was the answer after all, that OP expected :) He should be hiding some detail.